# Shadow from TOP and BOTTOM disappear after reload center FXML in BorderPane

Tags: javafx

I have a problem after reload center FXML in `BorderPane`.

The drop shadow in `top` and `bottom` elements disappear after that operation. 
I remarked that  I must always load center FXML at first.

Method. `toFront()` or `toBack()` throw a `NullPointerException`.

How can I reload one of the element and conserver the shadow from others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop shadow is not removed from the `top` and `bottom` elements. Instead the new `center` is added to the end of the child list and therefore is drawn on top of the other children which hides the drop shadow. To keep the order you have to add the children again in the correct order. This could be done using this little helper class:

```
public class BorderPaneReloadHelper {

    private List<ObjectProperty<Node>> permutation;

    public void before(BorderPane pane) {
        // get pane properties sorted by 
        final List<Node> children = pane.getChildren();
        permutation = Arrays.asList(pane.topProperty(), pane.leftProperty(), pane.bottomProperty(), pane.rightProperty(), pane.centerProperty());
        permutation.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> children.indexOf(p.get())));
    }

    public void after(BorderPane pane) {
        // before and after have to be called with the same argument
        if (permutation == null || permutation.get(0).getBean() != pane) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no corresponding before call");
        }

        Node[] nodes = permutation.stream().map(ObjectProperty::get).toArray(Node[]::new);
        pane.getChildren().removeAll(nodes);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            Node node = nodes[i];
            if (node != null) {
                permutation.get(i).set(node);
            }
        }

        // restore initial state to allow reuse of class
        permutation = null;
    }

}
```

It could be used like this:

```
BorderPaneReloadHelper helper = new BorderPaneReloadHelper();
helper.before(container);

... replace center...

helper.after(container);
```